# Laravel Edit Update JSON Array and remove specific input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, laravel

How can i load the JSON array saved in the database to the edit form input field ?

Here's how my create form looks like
[image]

Here's the form Code

```
        <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">
            Manage Extras
        </h5>


        <div class="card-body">

            <div class="optionBox">
                <div class="block main">
                    <div class="form-row pb-2">
                        <div class="col">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="extras_name[]" value="" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="extras_price[]" placeholder="Price">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <button type="button" class="remove btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block mt-2 ">
                        <button type="button" class="add btn btn-success">Add Extras</i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the Script to `Add Extra` input field and delete button

```
<script>
    $('.add').click(function() {
        $('.block:last').before('<div class="form-row pb-2"><div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="extras_name[]" placeholder="Name"></div><div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="extras_price[]" placeholder="Price"></div><div class="col"><button type="button" class="remove btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></div></div>');
    });

    $('.optionBox').on('click','.remove',function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
</script>
```

Here's how it saves in the database
[image]

Here's the `edit function` in the `Controller`

```
public function edit(CustomProduct $customProduct)
{

    $data = [
        'customProduct'=>$customProduct,
    ];

    return view('manage.custom-products.edit')->with($data);
}
```

I was able to load the data into the form using a foreach as below

```
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <strong>Names</strong>
                    @foreach ($customProduct['extras_name'] as $item)
                         <li>{{ $item }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <strong>Prices</strong>
                    @foreach ($customProduct['extras_price'] as $item)
                         <li>{{ $item }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here's how it was looking like
[image]

I just want to load the json  data into the input fields on edit and should be able to remove a pacific input by clicking the delete icon,

How can i do make this happen, Please help me out

Comment: Hi , did you tried below code ? Does that works for you ?

Comment: @Swati Yes i tried but it didn't work